# SQLite integer size: individually sized or for the entire group

Tags: sqlite

Taken straight off of SQLite's site "The value is a signed integer, stored in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value."

Does this mean that if you have 1 value that requires 8 bytes, ALL values in that column will be treated as 8 bytes. Or, if the rest are all 1 byte, and one value is 8 bytes, will only that value be using 8 bytes and the rest will remain at 1?

I'm more used to SQL in which you specify the integer size accordingly.

I know the question seems trivial, but based on the answer will determine how I handle a piece of the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sqlite database structure is different in the way it handles data types.  Each field can have a different type...

Here is the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/different.html) from sqlite:

> Most SQL database engines use static typing. A datatype is associated with each column 
>   in a table and only values of that particular datatype are allowed to be stored in that
>   column. SQLite relaxes this restriction by using manifest typing. In manifest typing, the
>   datatype is a property of the value itself, not of the column in which the value is 
>   stored. SQLite thus allows the user to store any value of any datatype into any column 
>   regardless of the declared type of that column. (There are some exceptions to this rule: 
>   An INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column may only store integers. And SQLite attempts to coerce 
>   values into the declared datatype of the column when it can.)

Comment: So essentially, it will fit each entry into the datatype as an integer (if it can), and will use the smallest iteration it can, regardless of the size or type of other entries in the column.

Comment: Yeah, you could even put a char in the same column and it will handle it.  Weird huh!

Comment: I read that as "chair" at first (it's late). Thanks for the response.

Comment: LOL.  Ok yeah that was funny.